# Transcluded isolate directive controller model not accessible in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

## !!!!!!!!!! Old Question

Just look at the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/LpaTDnXPgbezrhRb35Wp?p=preview) (**Outdated**). The isolated directive with template works, but the one accessing it in the view doesn't.

---

## The New One

I use the same [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LpaTDnXPgbezrhRb35Wp?p=preview) and I have listened to @Andrew Eisenberg suggestion to use transclution in my directive however it is still not working.

**HTML**

```
<p isolate-with-template></p>
<p isolate-with-transclude>Hello World {{vm.hi}}</p>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app',[])
.directive('isolateWithTemplate',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    scope:{},
    controller: function ($scope) {
      var vm = this;
        vm.hi = "hi";
    },
    template: "{{vm.hi}}"
  }
})
.directive('isolateWithTransclude',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
    controller: function ($scope) {
      var vm = this;
        vm.hi = "hi";
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Isolated scope directive expects a template

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you add content inside of a directive that is not transcluded, that content is overwritten by the directive.

In the case of your directive without a template, all of its content is simply removed. You can see this if you just replace `{{vm.hi}}` with any arbitrary text and you will see that it doesn't show either.

If you wanted to include `vm` in the view, you would need to transclude it by adding the `transclude` property to the directive definition. You would also need to add a template, but it could be empty. More information on [how to use transclude is available in the angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).

Comment: This is correct.  To add to this, Child Elements placed inside a directive tag *are not part of the directive*.

Comment: That is not true. I have updated the example to show a hello world text and it correctly displays

Comment: Hmmm....you're right. I would go back to my first (deleted) answer and say that it has something to do with `vm` not being in the scope of the child element.

Comment: Is there any ways to put vm in the view?

Comment: I would use the transclude property, but in order for that to work, you will need to include a template, but it can be empty.

Comment: Is that the only way? because I am using this directive on element that already has another directive that uses a templae. P.S.: can you post that as an answer

Comment: Can you post your comment as answer

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry !! But the problem still exist !! I have added transclution but I still can't access the view model. By the way I am sorry to reply so late because somehow stackoverflow didn't notify me on your update

Answer (score 0):

replace `scope: {},` to `scope: true,` in `isolateWithoutTemplate`

Comment: With `scope:true`, the scope is no longer isolate. It prototypically inherits from the parent scope.